# Can I upload iOS App to the App Store if Role is Member not Admin?

Tags: xcode, app-store-connect

I have member role accordingly Apple Developer Program Team Roles described here: https://developer.apple.com/support/roles/
And Developer role as App Storer connect user for the same team.
Every time I try to Distribute the app by uploading to the AppStore I have an error message that says "Role is Member, but at least Admin is required"
For other accounts, I have Admin rights and don't have such problems and it is unclear is it really possible to upload builds for Developer + Member role combination.
[image: error message]

I found that in some cases the reason for the error is missed certificate, but for this account, certificates are on the place:
[image: Certificates]

The same error happens if I try to add the project to the Xcode server for CI. What seems correct, because in all the documents Admin role is asked for this action.
[image: Xcode error]

Comment: Is the Apple ID part of the https://appstoreconnect.apple.com team as well?

Comment: Yes. Role in the app store connect is - Developer